# Merging netcdf files into one using R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have hundreds of daily netcdf containing geographic lat/long and parameters. I want to merge them into one file. So the time will only vary. I downloaded [NCO](http://nco.sourceforge.net/) but it is not very friendly for window users. I use [GrADS](http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/) to visualize. But to use GrADS, I need to merge the netcdfs first.

I would like to do this in R.

[image: EDIT:]

This is the screenshot of my folder. The issue is I want these 6-hourly netcdfs to become daily then combine the daily into  single netcdf file.

Is this possible?

Comment: In which way is NCO not friendly for Windows? I'm a Linux user, so I genuinely don't know. Because NCO would be perfect for this job...

Comment: @Janina: I do not have good background in unix environment

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcGIS Desktop (ArcMap)?

Comment: @user2543 I understand, but NCO should work in Windows as well.

Comment: @Janina. I downloaded them. Then I got lost in afterwardsm

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/nco/discussion/9830/thread/59fe446d/

Comment: @user2543 "Then I got lost in afterwardsm" what exactly went wrong?

Comment: Where are we starting from with you? Have you used R before? Do you know how to read the data into R? Have you used the `raster` package? Do all your NetCDF files have the same grid size and extent?

Comment: @Spacedman: Yes, same grid size and extent. But each file is daily. So I want to make a monthly data containing all files.

Comment: Give the R code you are using to read them. Also note that 100 of those will be about 2.7Gb, are you sure that whatever you are doing with these can cope with files of that size.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest trying NCO again, as it's well suited for this type of operation, and can be done with one command. The tool to concatenate several files along the record dimension (e.g. time) is [**`ncrcat`**](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncrcat). For example, to combine all the files for May 2018:

```
ncrcat gdaps_anal_201805????.nc gdaps_anal_201805.nc
```

The resulting file `gdaps_anal_201805.nc` should contain all 4x31=124 files worth of data, with a longer time dimension. Expect this to be a big file.